# I want to add a text in CKEditor and scroll the text to last. How to do that?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am retrieving old html data and adding new line like below:

```
var html = CKEDITOR.instances.ckEditor.getData().trim();
serial++;
CKEDITOR.instances['ckEditor'].setData(html +
                    '<div style="padding: 10px;font: 13px Tahoma; color: rgb(119, 119, 119);">'
                    + serial
                    + '.&nbsp;'
                    + "new data comes here"
                    + '</div>';
```

Now I this thing works but with a flick in editor. Is there any way to append the text in the last position? And I want to scroll the mouse cursor to last position of editor. How to do that? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *`And I want to scroll the mouse cursor`* You probably mean `"And I don't know how to set the caret after the last character"`?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/set-caret-position-0

Comment: No, I am using html div. So, It will automatically define a height. It doesn't need new line element.